# How to replicate do while in go?

Tags: for-loop, go, while-loop

I want a set of code to be executed until user explicitly wants to exit the function. For eg: when a user runs the program, he will see 2 options:

1. Run again
2. Exit

this will be achieved using switch case structure. Here if user presses 1, set of functions associated with 1 will execute and if user presses 2, the program will exit. How should i achieve this scenario in golang ? In java, i believe this could be done using do while structure but go doesn't support do while loop. Following is my code which i tried but this goes in a infinite loop:

```
func sample() {
    var i = 1
    for i > 0 {
        fmt.Println("Press 1 to run")
        fmt.Println("Press 2 to exit")
        var input string
        inpt, _ := fmt.Scanln(&input)
        switch inpt {
        case 1:
            fmt.Println("hi")
        case 2:
            os.Exit(2)
        default:
            fmt.Println("def")
        }
    }
}
```

The program irrespective of the input, prints only "hi". Could someone please correct me what wrong i am doing here ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When this question was asked this was a better answer *for this specific scenario* (little did I know this would be the #1 result when searching Google for "do while loop golang"). For answering this question generically please see [@LinearZoetrope's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32844744/455678).

Wrap your function in a for loop:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Press 1 to run")
    fmt.Println("Press 2 to exit")
    for {
        sample()
    }
}

func sample() {
    var input int
    n, err := fmt.Scanln(&input)
    if n < 1 || err != nil {
         fmt.Println("invalid input")
         return
    }
    switch input {
    case 1:
        fmt.Println("hi")
    case 2:
        os.Exit(2)
    default:
        fmt.Println("def")
    }
}
```

A `for` loop without any declarations is equivalent to a `while` loop in other C-like languages. Check out the [Effective Go documentation](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#for) which covers the `for` loop.

Comment: this only keeps on printing "hi". Even if we give command line input as 2, it prints "hi" instead of exiting the program.

Comment: My mistake. The switch case needs to be modified.

Comment: So the mistake with the original input was that the return value from Scanln was being used. The [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Scanln) states that the return is an error/number of arguments parsed, which is not how you want to use it. This should get you started.

Answer (score 83):

A `do..while` can more directly be emulated in Go with a for loop using a `bool` loop variable seeded with `true`.

```
for ok := true; ok; ok = EXPR { }
```

is more or less directly equivalent to

```
do { } while(EXPR)
```

So in your case:

```
var input int
for ok := true; ok; ok = (input != 2) {
    n, err := fmt.Scanln(&input)
    if n < 1 || err != nil {
        fmt.Println("invalid input")
        break
    }

    switch input {
    case 1:
        fmt.Println("hi")
    case 2:
        // Do nothing (we want to exit the loop)
        // In a real program this could be cleanup
    default:
        fmt.Println("def")
    }
}
```

Edit: [Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/MxNlCpeyOH) (with a dummied-out Stdin)

Though, admittedly, in this case it's probably overall clearer to just explicitly call (labelled) `break`, `return`, or `os.Exit` in the loop.

Comment: This should be accepted answer as it is idiomatic and exactly replicates `do while` whilst current accepted answer just replicates `while` statement

Comment: This is a great simple answer, however it doesn't allow you to access variables inside the for scope in the condition. [This answer solves this problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43643668/1541397)

Comment: @David Callanan I mean, it's not that hard to fix. Just do `ok = ok` for the expression and set `ok` manually at the end of the loop.

Comment: @LinearZoetrope Nice that works too! The condition is full of oks then :) `for ok := true; ok; ok = ok { ... }`

Answer (score 16):

The do...while in go can be this:

```
func main() {
    var value int
    for {
        value++
        fmt.Println(value)
        if value%6 != 0 {
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution allows you to access variables inside the for scope in the condition, which is necessary in some situations.

Answer (score 13):

a `while` loop in Go can be as easy as this:

```
  package main

  import `fmt`

      func main() {
        for {
          var number float64
          fmt.Print(`insert an Integer eq or gr than 10!!!`)
          fmt.Scanf(`%f`, &number)
          if number >= 10 { break }
          fmt.Println(`sorry the number is lower than 10....type again!!!`)
        }
```

Comment: This is an *infinite* loop declaration, rather than a while loop. A while loop would have a condition.

Comment: @VictorZamanian there is a condition: `if number >= 10 { break }`. For all intents and purposes, an infinite loop with a conditional break at the end is the same as a `do..while` loop which is exactly what OP was asking for.

Comment: @VictorZamanian perhaps I'm missing the point of your comment then. It sounds like you're trying to say that the answer is incorrect or that he's wrong to say that it's emulating a while loop.

Comment: @3ocene No, no. Your reasoning is correct. I probably just missed the condition at the end there when I made my first comment on this answer a while back. My mistake

Answer (score 4):

Conside to use "for-break" as "do-while".

*foo.go*

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
)

func main() {
        i := 0
        for {
                i++
                if i > 10 {
                        break
                }
                fmt.Printf("%v ", i)
        }
        fmt.Println()
}
```

*shell*

```
$ go run foo.go
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Comment: This is the same as `for i := 0; i < 10; i++ { fmt.Printf("%v ", i) }`. Perhaps you meant to put the print statement at the top of the loop?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not what you're looking for, but if you're trying to do something like this:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 10) {
    cout << "incrementing i now" << endl;
    i++
}
cout << "done"
```

You'll have to do something like this in go:

```
    var i = 0 
    fmt.Println(i)
    for {
            if i < 10 {
                    fmt.Println("incrementing i now")
                    i++ 
            } else {
                    break
            }   
    }   
    fmt.Println("done")
```

Comment: Go does have regular "while loops" though: `for a > b { ... }`. What OP is asking for is a `do { ... } while (a > b);` loop

Answer (score 1):

```
sum := 1
    for sum < 1000 {
        sum += sum
    }
```

Explanation :

The basic for loop has three components separated by semicolons:

-the init statement: executed before the first iteration.

-the condition expression: evaluated before every iteration

-the post statement: executed at the end of every iteration

The init and post statements are optional.

So you can just put in the condition expression.

```
// While (CONDITION = true){
//code to execute ....}

//In go : 
for CONDITION = true {
//code to execute}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the cleanest ways:

```
num := 10
for num > 0 {
    // do stuff here
    num--
}
```