# Working with returned value in [for] loop

Tags: go

I have an experience with C#, where I can work with commands from user like this:

```
string command;
while ( (command = GetCommandFromUser()) != EXIT_COMMAND )
    ProcessCommand(command);
```

This simple code allows me get command from user (from Console or something like this) and process it.

But in `Go` I have only this code:

```
var command string
for command = GetCommandFromUser(); command != ExitCommand; command = GetCommandFromUser() {
    ProcessCommand(command)
}
```

Can I do it simply?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32834661/how-to-replicate-do-while-in-go

Comment: @DavidG, you are wrong: this questions are different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for {
    command := GetCommandFromUser()
    if command == ExitCommand {
        break
    }

    ProcessCommand(command)
}
```

Comment: :) I know this way, but I think that it is not clean way.

Comment: This is probably about as clear as you'll get. You can't achieve the C# syntax you posted in Go.