# what does ok means for and if loops

Tags: go

Can someone explain what is happening below?
Why and when do we use ok in for loop?

```
distance := 0
for orbit, ok := orbits["ABC"]; ok; orbit, ok = orbits[orbit] {
    if _, ok := neworbits[orbit]; ok {
        fmt.Println(distance + neworbits[orbit])
        break
    }
    distance++
}
```

Comment: It's Go's version of a do-while https://yourbasic.org/golang/do-while-loop/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replicate do while in go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32834661/how-to-replicate-do-while-in-go)

Answer (score 3):

Map lookup has two forms:

```
x:=m[key]
```

This will lookup `key` in map `m`, and will return the corresponding value if it exists. If `key` does not exist, it will return the zero value for the value type.

```
x, ok=m[key]
```

This will also lookup `key` in map `m`, but will return (value,true) if the key exists, and (zero-value,false) if the key does not exist in the map.

In that example, `ok` will be true if the looked up key exists in the map.

Comment: Of course you can always substitute `ok` with a more descriptive variable name. It is just a variable declaration after all.

Comment: thanks ...this makes sense...but the only thing which is bothering me is again if _, ok := neworbits[orbits];ok..does this line mean if there is any value in the neworbits map the condition will be true..what does _ specify here ( any value will suffice?)..i read many documentation but cant find usage as used in this code :|

Comment: It is the blank identifier. The operation returns two values, but only one is used, so you use a blank identifier for the unused one instead of declaring an unused variable, because that would be a compile error

Comment: @abhishekchaudhry try searching the [language spec's web page](https://golang.org/ref/spec) for `, ok` and `_, ` and you'll find many short code examples of how the "comma-ok" idiom and the [blank identifier](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Blank_identifier) are used in Go.